# Changing Modules location in specific region

Tags: prism, prism-2

I've Prism App with some regions.

In one specific region there are some views from different modules. By default the views appears in region according to registration order.  I want to change the order appearance of views so that view from module c will appear first and not last.

I know it's possible to tell the module to depend by other module, but I want to change the views dynamically. I'm not sure it's possible. Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041765/prism-for-silverlight-how-to-maintian-views-in-specific-order-inside-a-region) deals with a similar situation, so you will probably find it useful.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian