# How to sort views in an ItemsControl in Prism / MEF?

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I use prism v4 and MEF to load my modules. My modules contain a handful of views (MVVM) which are loaded in a ItemsControl/NavigationRegion automatically by MEF.

This works nicely, all items show up in the ItemControl. But I don't like the order in which they show. One module might contain several of the items, so changing the module load order is not enough by itself.

How can I sort the different views in the ItemsControl? Is there any way to sort them by some property?

I use prism V4, MEF and exploration due to attributes like in the StockTraderRI example.

Comment: this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041765/prism-for-silverlight-how-to-maintian-views-in-specific-order-inside-a-region

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually baked into Prism4. Just apply the ViewSortHintAttribute to your views:

```
[ViewSortHint("100")]
class FirstView : UserControl { }

[ViewSortHint("200")]
class SecondView : UserControl { }
```

The default sort comparer on the regions will pick up this attribute and sort the views accordingly. You can put any string into the attribute but I tend to use medium sized numbers that allow me to easily put a new view in between existing ones.

Comment: Another attached property on `RegionManager` would make so much more sense to me. Attributes are compile-time constants, and they cannot be specified in XAML, which is helpful for some kinds of views that would not otherwise require code-behind. For example, a menu region would host menu items. Typically you would simply create a `MenuItem` and add it to the region, but you can't if you want to specify sort order!

Comment: Following on from my above comment, I've tackled this problem myself by defining a `Sort.Order` attached property (type `int`), then a `SortingRegionBehavior` that utilizes it. Finally, my bootstrapper registers this behavior as a default, so all regions will get it. The only limitation I've found so far is that changes to the `Sort.Order` property after the fact won't be reflected, but I'm pretty sure I can add support for that to my region behavior if I ever need it.

Answer (score 3):

Oh dang, this was **way** easier than I expected:

You can tell the region manager how to sort the views in a specific region. You just need to provide a compare function to the region.

This example sorts by a very stupid value, the function name:

```
private static int CompareViews(object x, object y)
{
  return String.Compare(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
}

this._regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].SortComparison = CompareViews;
```

Of course the region needs to be known to the region manager before you can set the SortComparison. So far the only workaround I found to achieve this was to defer to set the comparison function using the Dispatcher:

```
private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

[ImportingConstructor]
public ShellViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
  this._regionManager = regionManager;
  Dispatcher dp = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
  dp.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new ThreadStart(delegate
  {
    if (this._regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("MyRegion"))
      this._regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].SortComparison = CompareViews;
  }));
}
```

Of course one should use some more useful information than the class name for the sorting order, but this should be easy to solve (I'll just add an interface to all views which might be added to this region which provide a value to sort by).

Comment: I just added an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041765/prism-for-silverlight-how-to-maintain-views-in-a-specific-order-inside-a-region/4452910#4452910 which can be also interesting in this context.

Comment: I ran into a situation where I had views of the same type (and couldn't use ViewSortHint). I did get this SortCoparison delegate to work, eventually. I found that the delgate had to be set before adding the view that needed to be sorted. Otherwise, the views were displayed in the order added.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are looking for the [CollectionViewSource](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387). Bea provides some information on how to make use of it in the link.

From an MVVM stance this is how I use the `ICollectionView` within my ViewModel. The `_scriptService.Scripts` property is an `ObservableCollection<T>` getting wrapped in an `ICollectionView` which is returned to the View. The `_view.Filter` is being used to filter out items within the ICollection, thus changing the View. Similar to typing 'acc' and seeing all items that begin with 'acc' in your list.

```
    public class ScriptRepositoryViewModel : AViewModel
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
        private readonly IScriptService _scriptService;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        private ICollectionView _view;

        public ScriptRepositoryViewModel(IUnityContainer container, IScriptService scriptService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _container = container;
            _scriptService = scriptService;
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

        public ICollectionView Scripts
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_view == null)
                {
                    _view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_scriptService.Scripts);
                    _view.Filter = Filter;
                }

                return _view;
            }
        }
     }
```

Below is the code which takes care of the filtering, and is coming in via a `DelegateCommand` within Prism, this resides in the same ViewModel.

```
#region SearchCommand
public DelegateCommand<object> SearchCommand { get; private set; }

private String _search = String.Empty;
private void Search(object commandArg)
{
    _search = commandArg as String;
    _view.Refresh();
}

public bool Filter(object arg)
{
    bool usingPrefix;

    IScript script = arg as IScript;
    if (script.FileType == ConvertPrefixToFileType(_search, out usingPrefix))
    {
        if (_search.Length == 2)
            return true;
        else
            return CheckProperties(script, usingPrefix);
    }
    else
    {
        if (usingPrefix)
            return false;
        else
            return CheckProperties(script, usingPrefix);
    }
}
```

With the base functionality in place and making use of the `ICollectionView` you can apply your sorting as follows....

```
_view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PropertyName", direction));
```

More information on the sorting behavior can be found [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/), as there are some performance thoughts to keep in mind.

Comment: So, how would I use it in prism/MVVM?

Comment: @Sam Bea walks through it in the link above. Making use of the CollectionViewSource is not applicable per se to Prism, however it does fall in line with the MVVM pattern. Posted an example on how I use it.

Comment: Aaron, looks great, I gonna check it out and mark as answer as soon as I made it work, thanks!!

Comment: I tried your solution, but I don't understand how I get the CollectionView from the Region Manager (I'm trying to sort mef-loaded region content).

Comment: At the end of the day is the problem the order at which they are displaying on the screen? If this is the case then your ItemsControl you reference needs to be bound to something which is returning an ICollectionView.

Comment: My ItemsControl is "bound" to a prism region, and I got no idea how I'd get the prism regionmanager to use my ICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either [metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata) or properties. It depends on whether you have control over the interface or not...

Comment: I was rather looking for *how* to sort, not *by what*. If I get any example how sorting could be done I'll have no worries finding a property or metadata which I want to use for sorting.

Comment: Ahhh, well I know very little about WPF, so I can't help there!

Answer (score -2):

Views are displayed in the order they are added:

```
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ListRegion", typeof(ListView));
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ListRegion", typeof(ListView2));
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ListRegion", typeof(ListView3));
```

will look like:

----region--|
|  view3      |
|  view2      |
|  view       |

---